# function for getting text from cursor position in CKEditor acting strange

Tags: text, cursor, ckeditor

I'm trying to extract all text starting from the cursor position. Here is the code that I'm using:

```
originalText = editor.getData();
var startTag = "<span id=\x22Start\x22>&nbsp;</span>";
var stopTag = "<span id=\x22Stop\x22>&nbsp;</span>";
var startElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( startTag, editor.document );
editor.insertElement(startElement);
sText = editor.getData();
sText1 = sText + stopTag;
editor.setData(sText1);
// up to here, I've incapsulated the required text with span tags
// Using the replace function, I remove end tag of the Start span as well as removing    the start tag of the Stop span!
sText1 = editor.getData();
sText2 = sText1.replace("<span id=\"Start\">&nbsp;</span>", "<span id=\"Start\">");
sText2 = sText2.replace("<span id=\"Stop\">&nbsp;</span>", "</span>");
// I set the data (HTML) back to the editor
editor.setData(sText2);
//alert(sText2);
// I use the innerHTML to get the text
el = editor.document.$.getElementById("Start");
return el.innerHTML;
```

The problem:
   The el.innerHTML is working fine BUT ONLY if the alert() is uncommented! I know that setData is asynchronous and by using the callback on setData() would solve the problem but unfortunately it's not working for me :(

Comment: What are you trying to do? Meaning what are your recuirements? I think the answer here is to completely refactor the way you are doing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick fix to try would indeed be by using the callback. Using a callback you cannot return the el.innerHTML though, you would have to call an external function. You did not show the code that calls this code, so it's very hard to determine how to refactor this code to the way you want it. Below is a dummy version that is NOT tested and just serves to give you an example on how callbacks might be used.

```
function extractTextStartingFromCursorPosition(yourCallback) {
    originalText = editor.getData();
    var startTag = "<span id=\x22Start\x22>&nbsp;</span>";
    var stopTag = "<span id=\x22Stop\x22>&nbsp;</span>";
    var startElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( startTag, editor.document );
    editor.insertElement(startElement);
    sText = editor.getData();
    sText1 = sText + stopTag;

    editor.setData(sText1, function() {
        // up to here, I've incapsulated the required text with span tags
        // Using the replace function, I remove end tag of the Start span as well as removing    the start tag of the Stop span!
        sText1 = editor.getData();
        sText2 = sText1.replace("<span id=\"Start\">&nbsp;</span>", "<span id=\"Start\">");
        sText2 = sText2.replace("<span id=\"Stop\">&nbsp;</span>", "</span>");

        // I set the data (HTML) back to the editor
        editor.setData(sText2, function() {
            // I use the innerHTML to get the text
            el = editor.document.$.getElementById("Start");
            yourCallback(el.innerHTML);
        });
    });
}
```

So, if previously you used the function like this:

```
var html = extractTextStartingFromCursorPosition();
doSomethingWithHtml(html);
```

Now you would use it like this:

```
extractTextStartingFromCursorPosition(function(html) {
    doSomethingWithHtml(html);
});
```

Although I still feel that this functionality might be better done in some other way, but I don't have time to test/refactor a new solution for the same requirements.

Comment: Great work Nenotlep, that did it, I only needed to initialize the editor to its original content using another setData callback inside your second callback. By the way, sorry if this sounds so trivial but how can I extract the result outside the function? Thanks again.

Comment: @Mushahidi Nice to hear that! Actually that's a very good question and not trivial at all. It really depends on your situation and how you want to use it. by result I think you mean the `el.innerHTML`, right? Where and what would you want to do with it? I would insert everything that you need to use it in inside the `doSomethingWithHtml()` function, but it really depends a lot on the situation.

Comment: yes I do mean el.innerHTML. It's good that you said not trivial because I am having a hard time refactoring it. I wish I can put everything inside doSomethingWithHtml() but that's not an option! Anyway, with your help I am now a step forward.